# PyCharm - some breakpoints not working in a Django project

Tags: python, django, breakpoints, pycharm

I'm seeing some bizarre behaviour in PyCharm. I have a Django project where breakpoints stopped working in some files but not others. For example, all the breakpoints in my app's views.py work fine, but all the breakpoints in that same app's models.py are just ignored.

I've tried the following but no joy:

- double-check the breakpoints are enabled
- removing/re-adding the breakpoints
- closed/re-opened the project
- quit & re-launch PyCharm
- delete my configuration and create a new one

Some details:

- PyCharm 2.7.3
- Python 2.7.2 (within virtualenv)
- Django 1.5.1

I'm not using any special settings in my configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: Any symlinks in the project paths? If you have a reproducible test case, [file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: No symlinks, and I cannot reproduce on a different machine nor with a different project on the same box. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I don't know why or how, the problem was resolved by deleting the ".idea" directory within the Django project directory. This is where the PyCharm project data lives, so by removing this directory you will lose your project specific settings, so just be aware. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The problem for me is with the XML node <breakpoint-manager><breakpoins>...</breakpoints></breakpoint-manager> in the .idea/workspace.xml file. Just stop PyCharm, remove this section and start PyCharm, it will recreate it. Another solution for me was to remove all 'Python Line Breakpoints' from Breakpoints Window (Alt-F9). As you can see, there are some invalid breakpoints out there...

Answer (score 18):

If you have the setting "Gevent compatible debugging" enabled it does not seem to hit breakpoints in a non-Gevent django application.

Find it under *Preferences* -> *Python Debugger* -> *Gevent compatible debugging*

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE, THANK YOU SO MUCH, I COULDN'T GET THE DEBUGGER TO WORK IN 8 HOURS

Comment: Yes. Perfect answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, setting the "No reload" option in the run/debug configuration solved the problem. I'm using python 3.8.

Comment: But it will activate the --noreload of django server which means it will not load the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the breakpoint is **not** located in a project (dependency) **directly** symlinked from the project (the main project) that uses the symlinked project. I say directly, because PyCharm does follow breakpoints in symlinked projects located in site-packages, but this is an indirectly simlinked project.

Ex:

Scenario 1

Project A

- ProjB_SymLink

Site-Packages

- Other Packages

Scenario 2

Project A

Site-Packages

- ProjB_SymLink
- Other Packages

In Scenario 1, PyCharm will not see breakpoints located in code under Project B.
In Scenario 2, it will.

The below also should be useful:
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442551

Answer (score -1):

Just like other folders on the left side of your project, there will be a '.idea' folder on the top must be there. Delete that '.idea folder'. Close the project. Open it again. It solved my issues.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer.