# Pycharm 3 debugger not working with Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

[image]

I'm on win7 and using pycharm 3. I have set a breakpoint and hit the debug button. No errors whatsoever. The stepping through is greyed out.  The output is empty regardless of syntax errors. Running still works normally. My project settings are:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

edit: I have only 1 breakpoint on line 35 and it appears to be selected.

[image]

Comment: In `View Breakpoints ...` window  of `Run` menu ( short key: `Ctrl+Shift+F8`), is your breakpoint selected?

Comment: I've had breakpoints stop working on the Mac version before, and could only get them back working by removing the `.idea` directory for the project. [See my previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681731/pycharm-some-breakpoints-not-working-in-a-django-project)

Comment: Fiver I also tried your idea, but that did not work.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out and it appears to be working now at least . Make sure that Django exception breakpoint is checked.You can see above its not.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue earlier and noticed that IntelliJ launched several instances of my django project.
Closing IntelliJ (and all the running instances of the project) and trying again solved the issue

Comment: the default port could be used only once. how did multiple instances ran?

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I needed to restart PyCharm after configuring the project debugging options.